# Programmatically select html select element option

Tags: jquery

I want to select an option on a html select.  For example, a select with:

```
 <select id="list">
   <option>Jan</option>
   <option>Feb</option>
   <option>Mar</option>
   <option>Apr</option>
 </select>
```

I can do something like this if I know the value for the option, for example:

```
 <option value="0">Jan</option>

 $("#list option:eq(0)").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Can I use the value between the option tag?

Comment: option should have value attribute, then simply set select value. And FYI, using recent jQuery version, prop() to set selected property is the preferred method

Comment: I was trying to avoid repeating the value twice.

Comment: If you just have to use the text, you could always do `$('#list option:contains(Mar)').prop('selected', true)`

Comment: You confuse value and text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.val(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2), Here in example I have use `Mar` to set as value

> Set the value of each element in the set of matched elements.

```js
$("#list").val('Mar')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="list">
    <option>Jan</option>
    <option>Feb</option>
    <option>Mar</option>
    <option>Apr</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add value

```
<select id="list">
  <option value="jan">Jan</option>
  <option value="feb">Feb</option>
  <option value="mar">Mar</option>
  <option value="apr">Apr</option>
```

Then use jquery

```
$('#list').val( 'jan' );
```